# Delegating to a property of a property in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's consider the following code :

```kotlin
data class Location(var x:Int,var y:Int)
data class Player(val location:Location)

var Player.x: Int
    get() = location.x
    set(value) { location.x = value}
```

Is there a way to shorten this declaration using property delegates, in the style of `var Player.x by`  instead of of the last three lines ?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way works, using a [property reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#property-references):

```
data class Location(var x: Int, var y: Int)

data class Player(val location: Location) {
    var x by location::x
}
```

Comment: It works, but can you do that outside the Player class declaration, as an extension property ?

Comment: @Pylvain I can't find a way to do that, no…  I suspect the problem is that you'd need to provide the property reference directly when instantiating the extension property, but you can't, because it depends _indirectly_ on the Player instance it's being called on, and reference chaining doesn't seem to be supported.  (See [this thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/method-references-supplying-arguments-and-or-chaining/14123/4)?)